# VueJS Watch not working

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to watch a particular property of a component. The property is an array which gets's updated every time a checkbox is selected.

https://github.com/ratiw/vuetable-2/wiki/Special-Fields#-__checkbox

This is the code that I am trying with is like this

```
watch: {
    selectedTo: function(val){
          console.log(val);
    }
},
```

Neither did the below code work

```
 watch : { 
     selectedTo: { 
           handler(val, oldVal)
           { 
            console.log('Item Changed');
           }, 
           deep: true 
     } 
 },
```

Vue console: http://prntscr.com/gb1gew

Comment: is `selectedTo` supposed to be a function instead?

Comment: Well, it is a closure function since I need to pass the deep parameter as well. Also, I am not confident about my code since I am still learning Vue.

Answer (score 0):

You can watch `$refs.<name>.<data>` but not `$refs.<name>` itself.

Reference on this: https://jsfiddle.net/kenberkeley/9pn1uqam/

Still, though I don't know much about how your code works, try

```
this.$watch(() => this.$refs.vuetable.selectedTo, (val) => {...})
```